# Why histeq in Matlab is not working

Tags: matlab

I want equalize an image histogram. I tried the following code:

```
I = imread('1.png');
greyI = rgb2gray( I(:,:,1:3) );
J = histeq( greyI );
```

But the following warning occurred:

> ??? Attempt to execute SCRIPT histeq as a function:
>   D:\MatLab Prog\histeq.m
>   
>   Error in ==> histeq at 3
>   J = histeq( greyI );

I also tried to get help from about `histeq` function, but that returns

> No help found for histeq.m.

Help from you would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @ssavi you have may of your questions still open without an accepted answer.When a answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created your own file called histeq, see the error message. Delete or rename it to resolve the program.

Comment: Thanks .. I Have deleted those files .